# Premise Discharge with vertical dots with bussproof.sty

Tags: logic, proof-package, bussproofs

Is it possible with `bussproof.sty` package to obtain a discharge of premiss with vertical dots? Ex:
With `proof.sty` package I use `\infer*` to obtain vertical dots discharge

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs, proof}
\begin{document}
\infer{C}{A \vee B & \infer*{C}{[A]} & \infer*{C}{[B]} }
\end{document}
```

But with `bussproof.sty` package I'm not able to obtain vertical dots discharge. Ex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs, proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$A \vee B$}
    \AxiomC{[$A$]}
    \noLine
    \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \AxiomC{[$B$]}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$C$}
\TrinaryInfC{$C$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could fake it in something like the following way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bussproofs,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$A \vee B$}
  \AxiomC{[$A$]}
  \noLine
  \UnaryInfC{$\vdots$}
  \noLine
  \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \AxiomC{[$B$]}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\vdots$}
        \noLine
        \UnaryInfC{$C$}
\TrinaryInfC{$C$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: faked vertical discharge]